# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Broken by my reckless package removal

Tags: upgrade, python

I've been using Linux for some time now but as my second OS (3 years I guess).
I recently had to build a new machine and I decided to use Linux only (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

It was my first time personalizing Ubuntu, I did it just right, but I had issues removing GRUB boot menu (it was UEFI installation). 
I read somewhere that I have to upgrade Python.

I don't remember what version I had but I think it was 2.7 and it was set as system default.
I installed python 3.8 but I was unable (by my lack of knowledge) to set it as system default.

So I did:

```
sudo apt remove python
```

Everything seems to be just normal. But when I restarted PC, GNOME was gone, networking was gone.

I read that the best way to restore is to make a backup of my files and reinstall system.

I don't want to make this mistake again so I also want to know how to do a successful upgrade of python in the future.

Greetings,
Aftermathx25

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it now

Comment: Close vote retracted!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall Python 2.7 (that's the standard for many systems tools) in order to use Python 3.X. When you get to install it again, you'll refer to them  as Python and Python3.

Comment: What I really mean was how to set Python 3.X to be run when you use Python command instead of Python3.

Answer (score 0):

If apt does not work, then you must manually download dependencies to repair apt:

- Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com. Use ONLY the sections for your current release of Ubuntu. Using wrong-version packages will make the problem worse.
- Download the `python-minimal` package. Install it using `sudo dpkg --install`
- If dpkg returns dependency errors, download and install each dependency package too. Fix every error before moving on - do not skip steps.
- Finally, try `sudo apt install python`

When apt is working properly and without any errors:

- `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to restore the rest of your system.